How to boost FPS for animation in Blender?
I need some advice on how to improve FPS in the viewport while working with animation.
The issue is that the same model runs at 40 FPS in Maya but only reaches 12 FPS max in Blender! The model is around 200k faces (no modifiers or subdivisions), and I'm importing the rig and animation from Maya.
PC specs: RTX 4090, Ryzen 9 7950X, and 64GB RAM.
What I’ve tried so far:

Decimate Modifier - FPS actually got worse. It seems like the modifier needs to be applied, but that's not an option right now. Solid View - This does give the highest FPS, as
expected.
Disabling Overlays, Effects, and Anti-Aliasing - Doesn't help much.
Turning off Graph Editor window - Even in full screen, I didn’t see any significant FPS increase.
Playback > Sync > Frame Dropping - This doesn't boost FPS; it just skips frames to keep up with the animation.
I might have tried some other things, but I can't recall...

Any tips or ideas would be appreciated!

Hello, do you mean that you are in Rendered preview and Cycles?

I cannot tell how often I commented here that the FPS setting was never meant to be perfectly working in the viewport. It is a setting in the Output Properties, mainly needed if you render directly to a video file which has to have an FPS setting and for simulations to be calculated properly for the intended playback speed. It is also used for playback of previously rendered animations. Blender will always have problems playing animations in the viewport if the scene is using a lot of resources.

One tip that some animation tutorials usually give to check if the animations look good at the correct speed is rendering quick previews from the viewport, with View > Viewport Render Animation. They are rendered much faster than normal renders (even EEVEE renders), and you are not limited to the camera's view, you can basically render any view you are currently looking at in the viewport, maybe to check how something looks from a different perspective (or orthographic) or to see something closer in more detail etc.

@moonboots no, i'm working in solid view, of course

@GordonBrinkmann yeah, thanks! but i'd like to use this method as a last resort :)

@EvgeniyPupkin So, what do you actually want from us? As far as I can tell, you've done almost everything you could. If there is something in your scene which could be improved, we cannot tell from just knowing it is a model with 200k faces, nothing about the rig or animation or anything else. And keeping in mind that there are scenes which simply cannot run at the desired FPS in Blender... the fact that Maya runs quicker doesn't say anything. Fire simulations run faster in EmberGen than in Blender as well. That doesn't mean Blender is able to do the same.

As Gordon say,  View > Viewport Render Animation is probably the best to have a quick preview of the real speed of your animation, I don't think that there's any trick except the ones you cite, like drop frames, or hide some objects of your scene...

thanks for the replies, guys. another thing i found is that collapsing all meshes gives you 5-7 more FPS

I'm not sure if I know what you mean by "collapsing all meshes" in this case, as I said we don't really know anything about your scene so it's hard to give more specific tips than what you already tested yourself.
